# Guest user cart automatically empties itself after 1 hour

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.4, guest-checkout

I am facing an issue where the products added in the cart automatically gets removed after 1 hour. I am facing this issue only for guest user.

I have checked the following values and found them to be OK,

I set [ Persistence Lifetime (seconds) ] : 31536000

[image]

I have checked the [ session.gc_maxlifetime ] : 1440

[image]

I set the [ Cookie Lifetime ] : 86400

[image]

Now I am not sure what I need to check further in order to fix this issue. Could someone plz suggest or guide me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To configure it, check the admin `cookie lifetime` (make sure to configure the `cookie domain`) and the session.gc_maxlifetime.

**Path** :     Admin -> Configuration -> Stores -> -General -> Web -> Default Cookie Settings

Please try this once.

Comment: I have update my question according to your suggestion, but still I am having this issue. Any other suggestion